# Nextcloud snap version - How to edit configuration?

Tags: nextcloud

I installed nextcloud using `sudo snap install nextcloud` on my vps. Now I can connect to it at *localhost:80* from the vps itself. If I forward the 80-th port via ssh from my local computer, then I can connect from it too. I want nextcloud to work at *nextcloud.mydomain.dmn*, so I obviously need to do some configuration, however I don't know how to do that with **snap**.

There is a readonly `/snap/nextcloud/current/` directory with `conf/httpd.conf`. I can't edit it. It's provided by the following systemd unit:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/snap-nextcloud-2184.mount
[Unit]
Description=Mount unit for nextcloud

[Mount]
What=/var/lib/snapd/snaps/nextcloud_2184.snap
Where=/snap/nextcloud/2184
Type=squashfs
Options=nodev,ro

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It seems there are not nextcloud-related config files in `/etc` except for systemd units.

Answer (score 4):

The Nextcloud snap is as far I can see not using a vhost, so it doesn't serve Nextcloud for specific domains. You should open port 80 and 443 on your VPS and setup DNS so `nextcloud.mydomain.dmn`points to your VPS.

You'll have to configure Nextcloud to trust this new domain, this is described here (https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/wiki/Connecting-the-Nextcloud-Box-to-the-Internet#3-add-your-external-domain-to-nextcloud):

> List the domains you're currently using
>
> `sudo nextcloud.occ config:system:get trusted_domains`
>
> Create a new entry
>
> `sudo nextcloud.occ config:system:set trusted_domains 2 --value=nextcloud.mydomain.dmn`
>
> Note: replace "your.domain" with the domain name registered at step 1
>   and replace the number 2 with the actual number where the new entry
>   will be created. For a 3rd entry, you would use the number 3

That's it. Here is some more information about the snap:
 - https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/wiki/Included-CLI-utilities
 - https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/wiki/Enabling-HTTPS-(SSL,-TLS)

Answer (score 0):

Nextcloud lauches his own Apache server when installed through snap. By default, it listens on port 80.

([source](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/wiki/Enabling-HTTPS-(SSL,-TLS))) You can activate ssl with:

```
sudo nextcloud.enable-https lets-encrypt
```

and add your domain to trusted domains in:

```
/var/snap/nextcloud/current/nextcloud/config/config.php
```

([source](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap)) You can also change the port:

```
sudo snap set nextcloud ports.https=444
```

And serve it behind a proxy.

Comment: I tried the "serve it behind a proxy" route but it is quite involved and in the end I never got it working properly. Stuff like file uploads still randomly break when the service is put behind nginx.

Comment: I am serving it behind a nginx proxy without any problem. (not the snap version)